# Why does this inequality hold $|\int_T \frac {|x|} {\sqrt n} dx - \frac {1} {\sqrt 3}| \leq \sqrt 3 \int_T |\frac {|x|^2} {n} - \frac 1 3 | dx$?

Tags: analysis, inequality

why does this inequality hold?
$$\left|\int_T \frac {|x|} {\sqrt n} \mathrm{d}x - \frac {1} {\sqrt 3}\right| \leq \sqrt 3 \int_T \left|\frac {|x|^2} {n} - \frac 1 3 \right| \mathrm{d}x$$
with $T=[0,1]^n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply triangle inequality for the integral then use the fact that $|\frac{|x|^2}{n}-\frac{1}{3}| = |\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}| \cdot |\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|$.